# Linux `sort` doesn't work on numeric field

Tags: linux, sorting

Here is a sample text file:

```
Peter:123777:ETA  
Joan:16466:HLT  
John:11223:HR  
David:23456::::FSI  
George::::876543:ECS
```

The task is to sort on second field, so I did the below:

```
cat input.txt | tr -s ":" | cut -d':' -f1,2,3 | sort -t':' -k2
```

Here is the output:

```
John:11223:HR   
Peter:123777:ETA  
Joan:16466:HLT  
David:23456:FSI  
George:876543:ECS
```

But it doesn't sort. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

I tried searching with "Linux sort doesn't work" and checked few answers. But not able to understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it doesn't sort.

It does sort; the sequence in the output is different than in the input. It just doesn't sort in the way you expected.

`123777` sorts before `23456` because in your locale `1` sorts before `2` (I guess it is so in any sane locale). If you want *numeric* sort then you need to tell this to `sort`:

- by using the global option `-n`: `sort -n -t':' -k2`
- or by including `n` in the definition of the key: `sort -t':' -k2n`.